# Getting Axios params to work in Async/Await function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

What am I missing in this call? Does the async nature of `asyncData` affect the request's ability to load the param in? The network tab returns a `304` code, but no data is fetched from the backend.

```js
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loggedInUser"])
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: "Actors list"
    };
  },
  components: {
    EditProfile
  },
  async asyncData() {
    try {
      let actors = await $axios.$get(`/api/v1/actors/`, {
        params: {
          user: this.loggedInUser.id
        }
      });
      
      return { actors };
    } catch (e) {
      return { actors: [] };
    }
  },
```

Comment: 304 means the data is cached (no call to the backend). clear your cache and try again.

Comment: @HassenCh. Hey, just tried that, and got the same thing with no data. Any other possible fixes?

Comment: I guess you should share more code. Can you add your backend code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Just realize that asyncdata doesn't allow the use of 'this' or other variables from store since it's the first thing to be loaded.